# Set audio port from audio input to audio output on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, speakers

On my mac I have one audio port. In System Preferences I can set this as audio output or audio input (for a microphone for example).

I need to connect a sound system (Creative desktop theatre DTT2200) to another laptop with windows 10 I have two audio ports (one for output one for input). For this I need at least two audio output ports. I need to change the audio input port to audio output so that I get two audio output.

I cannot find a Control Panel preference to set it.

What is the proper way to change this on the windows 10? Do I need an external software to do it?

Comment: Why do you need two audio outputs?

Comment: I ca now only use two of the speakers(satellites) in addition to the subwoofer. As i see from th [from the usaers guide](http://files2.europe.creative.com/manualdn/Manuals/TSD/727/English.pdf) page 10 the better way than using only two speakers is the way it depicts with two ports. I think maybe I can use more of the satellites this way.

Answer (score 3):

The microphone input on your PC can **not** be used for output under any circumstances.  The port on the Mac is made specifically to support both operations but that is not usual in other sound adapters.

Even if you could convert the microphone port to an output, it would still not work with existing software (drivers and applications) to output multi-layered audio.

What you really need is a USB Dolby 5.1 sound adapter.